# The electron volt equation and momentum

Tags: electrons

Can someone explain to me how one goes from eV $= \frac{1}{2} mv^2$ to eV$ = \frac{1}{2} p^2/m$?

I've tried several ways of rearranging it but it never comes close to the final form.

Comment: There is nothing special about using electron volts as energy units in this equivalence.

Comment: What is p?  It is not explained

Comment: $p$ is momentum.   $p=mv$.  Plug that into the second equation and you will wind up with the first.

Comment: Good grief...have you bothered setting $mv^2=p^2/m$ and trying to find out what $p$ might need to be?

Comment: @KyleKanos looks like $p=mv$!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Well, I was just asking

Comment: @DellaDellaRae  If you know what momentum is, then you should do the very simple algebra yourself rather than asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron volt equation that you are using is more generally known to be the kinetic energy equation. Formally known as,

$$\text{KE} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

To my knowledge, there is no real reason why electronvolts (eV, really a unit of energy) makes this equation special enough to be called the electronvolt equation. Perhaps someone can explain this to me.

However, to answer your question, momentum ($p$) is equal to the product of the mass ($m$) of an object and its velocity ($v$). Thus,

$$ p = mv \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad v = \frac{p}{m}$$

This may then be put into the first equation, such that,

$$\text{KE} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}m \left(\frac{p}{m} \right)^2$$

Thus,

$$\text{KE} = \frac{1}{2}m \frac{p^2}{m^2} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{p^2}{m}$$

Which, using your eV notation, would then imply that,

$$\text{KE} = \text{eV} = \frac{p^2}{2m} $$

Comment: Please don't waste your time answering such terrible questions on this site. It just encourages more of this lazy posting "do this work for me" type questions that we explicitly do not want around here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't understand what was wrong I didn't mean to come across that way, what was the proper way? Anyway I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Kyubey. This is a perfectly good answer and I've upvoted it. I think Kyle must be feeling grumpy at the moment :-)

Comment: An up vote from me as well. Well written and simple answer.

Comment: Of course, if the velocity is very high, then it gets a little trickier because we need to use the relativistic versions of these equations. But for $v<.1c$  the relativistic correction is tiny.

Comment: @JohnRennie not grumpy, just hate low quality questions getting answers.  Kyubey's time would be better spent answering good questions, rather than these terrible ones.